# Inverse Limit as a Functor, is this correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Suppose we have a homomorphism $\psi: R/I^n\to S/J^n$.

Does it follow from the fact that inverse limit is a functor that it extends to a homomorphism

$$\widetilde{\psi}: \varprojlim R/I^n\to \varprojlim S/J^n$$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes: functors send morphisms to morphisms.

Comment: Thanks. According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit), the inverse limit $\varprojlim: C^{I^{op}}\to C$ is a functor. I am concerned about the $C^{I^{op}}$, and whether my question still holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- The inverse limit is a covariant functor from [the category of directed systems in $C$] to $C$.
- The category of directed systems in $C$ has a slick description in terms of the opposite category of some category describing the indexing, which is what the Wikipedia article you're linking is doing. But you should not think the inverse limit itself is a contravariant functor; it is covariant (as the page explicitly says).
- Your notation is a little ambiguous. To get a morphism of directed systems, we don't just want one $\psi$, but for each $n$ we want a $\psi_n: R/I^n \to S/J^n$. Further, we require that these commute with the natural quotient maps $R/I^n \to R/I^{n-1}$ and $S/J^n \to S/J^{n-1}$. It's only with this data that we get a morphism of inverse limits (EDIT: or rather, it's only with this data that we get a morphism of inverse limits by directly appealing to functoriality -- see the comments).

Comment: The last sentence of this answer should probably say that it's only from these data that we get a morphism of inverse limits **directly from functoriality**. Other situations might get us a morphism of inverse limits via some additional work.

Comment: @AndreasBlass good point! I'll edit it into the answer.